# .net core xslt transformation EntryPointNotFoundException when run in docker (linux)

Tags: docker, .net-core, .net-standard, xslcompiledtransform

I try to perform xslt transformation using `XsltCompiledTransformation`class.
The code is pretty standard.
The problem is when I run on local windows environment everything works as expected but when I try the same on docker I have the next error

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Entry point was not found.
at System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1.get_Count()  
at <xsl:template name="MyTemplate">(XmlQueryRuntime , IList`1 , IList`1 , IList`1 , IList`1 , String )
```

Maybe someone had similar error?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm struggling with the same problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

for me, setting

`enableDebug` to `true` when creating my `XslCompiledTransform` class somehow fixes this.  <s>I should note my xslt makes use of `msxsl:node-set`</s> It doesn't seem to matter what is in the XSLT.

This feels more like a bug than a proper solution.